# odata datajs CRUD operation fails in IE (OData)

Tags: jsonp, wcf-data-services, odata, datajs

I have this code below, which adds a new "Activity" in my "activity" table/entity thru WCF Data Services. Now all is fine and dandy when I run this in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE10 it responds with the following error...

```
{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request."}}}
```

Here is what my code looks like...

```
function addActivity( newActivity )
    {
        var newActivity = { ActivityName: newActivity };
        var requestOptions = {
            //headers: { "DataServiceVersion": "1.0" },
            method: "POST",
            requestUri: uriActivity,
            data: newActivity
        };
        OData.request( requestOptions, AddSuccessCallback, AddErrorCallback );

    }
```

I'm also using the following packages, for all it's worth...Thanks a lot for reading up to here. Many special thanks in advance for your input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="datajs" version="1.0.3" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.7.2" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.0.1" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.0.1" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services" version="5.0.1" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.0.1" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.0.1" />
</packages>
```

Trace looks like this...

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 09 Jul 2012 07:55:17 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
DataServiceVersion: 1.0;
Content-Length: 1159
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
Connection: Close

{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request."},"innererror":{"message":"A node of type 'EndOfInput' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read the start of an entry. A 'StartObject' node was expected.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.ODataJsonEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadEntryStart()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.ODataJsonReader.ReadEntryStart()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.ODataJsonReader.ReadAtStartImplementation()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.Read()\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntityDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataReader odataReader, SegmentInfo topLevelSegmentInfo)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntityDeserializer.Read(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)\r\n   at System.Data.Services.Serializers.ODataMessageReaderDeserializer.Deserialize(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)"}}}
```

Comment: Could you please use this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx to get a more detailed error message to see what's wrong? Also a trace of the request/response might help, you can use for example fiddler for that (and compare IE to Chrome/Firefox).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Vitek. I think the setting **config.UseVerboseErrors = true;** mentioned in that post will help me a lot going forward. I wasn't aware of it. However my response is more IE10 specific. I have just changed the **Document Mode: IE9 Standards** in developer tools, and everything works fine. Now it leaves me wondering, what could IE10 be doing. Many thanks.

Comment: I understand that your problem is IE10 specific, but without knowing why the request fails, it's hard to guess what's wrong. Given the error, could you please also post the request trace (not just the response). That error probably means that the payload of the request is not complete or even empty when it should not be.

Comment: Looks like I need to serve my pages thru HTTP. Loading them from Windows doesn't work especially where IE is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to serve my pages thru HTTP. Loading them from Windows doesn't work especially where IE is concerned.

Comment: If you open the HTML page from your disk directly, then IE won't run scripts in it (unless you allow that, or use special marks in the HTML page)... is that what you were hitting?